# JQuery console error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do a content slider controlled with a menu. Div elements will be placed in a wrapper and I am changing its position using script. Please check below code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    function goto(id){
        jQuery(".contentbox-wrapper").animate({"left": -(jQuery(id).position().left)}, 600);
    }
});
```

and html where the function calling is,

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="goto('#homePage', this); return false">Home</a></li>

<li><a href="#" onClick="goto('#aboutPage', this); return false">About</a></li>
```

and the content divs is like

```
<div class="contentbox-wrapper">
    <div id="homePage" class="contentBox">
        content here
    </div>
    <div id="aboutPage" class="contentBox">
        content here
    </div>
</div>
```

the problem is, when i click on the menu items i am getting this error

" Uncaught ReferenceError: goto is not defined "

Please help..

Comment: The only way for an inline handler to find the function is if it's a global function. Yours is defined locally to the `.ready()` callback. Move it outside. There's no need to wait for the DOM to be ready to declare your function.

Comment: Also, the `goto` name may not work in order browsers, since in ECMAScript 3 it was a reserved word.

Comment: Why not bind to the click event in the jQuery DOM ready scope instead of using onClick?

Comment: @scrowler I'm a beginner in javascript.. don't know how to.. Thanks for your help..

Comment: @cookiemonster rightnow I am not concerned with older browsers, atleast need to work in new browsers.. :-) thanks for the help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the goto function outside the document ready event handler function.
Also your function is taking a single parameter but you're using two every time you call it (not the case, just doesn't make much sense).

Answer (score 0):

You're passing goto two parameters when you reference it in the onclick attributes of the links but in its definition it only accepts a single param, the id.